# No valid OpenPGP data found - Elasticsearch wget

Tags: gpg, certificates, elasticsearch

I am trying to install elasticsearch on Ubuntu 20.04, but I am getting the following error:

```
home@VirtualBox$ wget -qO - https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch | sudo apt-key add -
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

I also tried the following with no luck:

```
VirtualBox:~$ wget -qO - https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch -O mykey
VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt-key add <<< mykey
[sudo] password for VirtualBox: 
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

I already updated Ubuntu packages:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

How could I solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try to get the code without adding it? It may be the link you are trying to get the gpg code from is corrupted and not updated on the docs yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try to download just the key as follows:

```
wget -O key https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch --no-check-certificate
```

The problem might be an issue with with certificates